# Timing shared library load times on linux

Tags: c++, linux, redhat, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to figure out how much time I'm taking in loading shared libraries on a linux system (RHEL 6 to be specific) and I'm wondering what sort of tools are out there to time how long shared library loading takes. I haven't really found any good information out there as to how to do this and I'm hoping some sort of tool exists.

Comment: The dynamic linker can provide some information. See LD_DEBUG : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Comment: do you wnt to know that for explicit dlopen() or loads done by the loader when you start your program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run under `LD_DEBUG=statistics`:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=statistics ls > /dev/null
      9897:
      9897:     runtime linker statistics:
      9897:       total startup time in dynamic loader: 1557664 clock cycles
      9897:                 time needed for relocation: 322049 clock cycles (20.6%)
      9897:                      number of relocations: 156
      9897:           number of relocations from cache: 8
      9897:             number of relative relocations: 1257
      9897:                time needed to load objects: 1037549 clock cycles (66.6%)
```